# python3 не работает whois

Tags: python-3.x, whois

Пробовал различные варианты получения данных о домене, ошибки..

```
import pythonwhois
details = pythonwhois.get_whois('google.com')
print(details)
```

Ошибка:

```
      File "c:/Users/len/Desktop/w.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pythonwhois
  File "C:\Users\len\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pythonwhois\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import net, parse
  File "C:\Users\len\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pythonwhois\parse.py", line 363, in <module>
    registrant_regexes = [preprocess_regex(regex) for regex in registrant_regexes]
  File "C:\Users\len\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pythonwhois\parse.py", line 363, in <listcomp>
    registrant_regexes = [preprocess_regex(regex) for regex in registrant_regexes]
  File "C:\Users\len\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pythonwhois\parse.py", line 205, in preprocess_regex
    regex = re.sub(r"\\s\*\(\?P<([^>]+)>\.\+\)", r"\s*(?P<\1>\S.*)", regex)
  File "C:\Users\len\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 192, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "C:\Users\len\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 309, in _subx
    template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
  File "C:\Users\len\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 300, in _compile_repl
    return sre_parse.parse_template(repl, pattern)
  File "C:\Users\len\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 1024, in parse_template
    raise s.error('bad escape %s' % this, len(this))
re.error: bad escape \s at position 0
```

Не могу понять, почему такая мелочь не работает. В онлаин интерпретаторе все ок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, это баг. Документации и описания этого модуля на [PiPI](https://pypi.org) нет.

Для этих целей могу посоветовать Вам [python-whois](https://pypi.org/project/python-whois/).

Для установки введите в консоли (или терминале):

```
pip install python-whois
```

Пример:

```py
import whois


w = whois.whois('ru.stackoverflow.com')
print(w)
```

*stdout:*

```html
{
  "domain_name": "STACKOVERFLOW.COM",
  "registrar": "Name.com, Inc.",
  "whois_server": "whois.name.com",
  "referral_url": null,
  "updated_date": "2019-01-11 17:52:14",
  "creation_date": "2003-12-26 19:18:07",
  "expiration_date": "2020-02-02 11:59:59",
  "name_servers": [
    "NS-1033.AWSDNS-01.ORG",
    "NS-358.AWSDNS-44.COM",
    "NS-CLOUD-E1.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM",
    "NS-CLOUD-E2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM",
    "ns-1033.awsdns-01.org",
    "ns-358.awsdns-44.com",
    "ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com",
    "ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com"
  ],
  "status": [
    "clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited",
    "clientTransferProhibited https://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited"
  ],
  "emails": [
    "abuse@name.com",
    "sysadmin-team@stackoverflow.com"
  ],
  "dnssec": [
    "unsigned",
    "unSigned"
  ],
  "name": "Sysadmin Team",
  "org": "Stack Exchange, Inc.",
  "address": "110 William St , Floor 28",
  "city": "New York",
  "state": "NY",
  "zipcode": "10038",
  "country": "US"
}
```

**UPD:**
Если возникает ошибка `AttributeError: module 'whois' has no attribute 'whois'`, попробуйте исполнить следующие команды в консоли (или терминале):

```
pip uninstall whois 
pip install python-whois
```

Comment: было бы хорошо, но опять беда. в данном случе выдает ошибку module 'whois' has no attribute 'whois'. * все библиотеки выполняющие whois, кроме python-whois, удалены

Comment: @Laoris Приведите, пожалуйста, полный текст ошибки, постараюсь помочь. Я проверял данный код и уверен, что он работает.

Comment: сам код идентичен вашему, может беда со связями в питоне? File "F:\admin\1-whois.py", line 22, in <module>
    w = whois.whois('ru.stackoverflow.com')
AttributeError: module 'whois' has no attribute 'whois'

Comment: @Laoris Скорее всего, это не та библиотека. Попробуйте удалить её, я обновил ответ.

Comment: nomnoms12, спасибо!